# Display image using ireport and oracle xe and apex

Tags: image, oracle, ireport, oracle-apex

I am using ireport 5.1 to build my report, now I am trying to display an image in my pdf report, but it is not showing up.

I copied the jpg file to the jasper directory where I have my ireport compiled file ( jrxml ),
I am referencing the jpg file in my report as :

XML CODE :

```
        <image>
            <reportElement uuid="generated_uuid" x="2" y="4" width="119" height="50"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["logovinhedo.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code snippet:

1. Store the full image path in a parameter `IMAGE_PATH`
2. Apply the parameter instead of image file name.

> ```
> <image>
>     <reportElement x="2" y="4" width="119" height="50" />
>     <imageExpression class="java.lang.String">!CDATA[$P{IMAGE_PATH}]]> </imageExpression>
> </image>
> ```